# Maven child module to be dependent on all other children modules without adding dependency

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a maven aggregation project which is setup like this:

```
main_project
   ->common_submodule
   ->child_a
   ->child_b
   ...
   ->child_x
   ->webapps
```

Other developers could add their own submodules, and all these submodules should be integrated by webapps submodule which loads their beans, so it has to be dependent on all other submodules. I would like to keep webapps submodule closed for changes, so it would be great if there is some way to make these submodules available on webapps classpath without adding dependencies in its pom.

Comment: First this is not possible cause if you like to have the submodules on the classpath you must given the information somehow to the webapps module which means you need to add the dependency in the webapps pom...? What is the real problem with that?

Comment: Project is a framework and different developers will build their own submodules on top of it, without any collaboration between each other. I wanted to limit them to change only their submodules without making changes to common parts of the application to avoid potential problems and conflicts which might happen. It's not a big problem if they have to change this file, but I thought that there might be some elegant solution that would make it possible.

Comment: And what i forgot to say you need to define those dependency to make sure the build order is correct...cause in your case webapps must be build last....

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have good reasons for this.

You have tow ways to get additional modules as dependencies in your webapps.

1. new modules as transitive dependency: by adding the new module as
   dependency in one of already referenced modules in webapps e.g (child_a or child_b). 
   Note: I'm strongly advise against this option.
2. main_project as parent project for your webapps, So you can add the
   new modules as dependencies in the main_project, which will be
   inherited in the webapps.

hope this helps.

Comment: First option you suggested doesn't solve the problem I have. Actually, it would be even worse in my scenario. Second option can't work. It would make a cyclic reference between children I added as dependencies in main_project